# How to change div background with color picker angular js

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to change the background color of a couple of divs based on the choosen color from a colorpicker.

I have tried it using this:

```
<div ng-style="[id^='color']{background-color: '{{rgbPicker.color}} !important}'">
    <div bind-html-compile="body">
        <div id="color1"></div>
        <div id="color2"></div>
        <div id="color3"></div>
        <div id="color4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the right color code in `rgbPicker.color` (hex code), but the color is not changing. How can I make this work?

Comment: maybe add `#` before the color value

Comment: @TemaniAfif the `#` is already added by the colorpicker.

Comment: ng-style="{'background-color':'{{rgbPicker.color}}'}">

Comment: I don''t think so that you need add selector for 'ng-style'. You should type: <div ng-style="{background-color: '{{rgbPicker.color}} !important}'">. If rgbPicker.color is in hex mode then you should use: <div ng-style="{background-color: '#{{rgbPicker.color}} !important}'">.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need / want to go through the `ngStyle` directive, when all you want is to set a background color? Here is a dead simple example using the default `<input>` color picker which updates the `<body>` background in a `$watch` :

```html
<input type="color" ng-model="color">
```

```js
$scope.color = '#ffffff'
var body = document.querySelector('body');  
$scope.$watch('color', function(newVal) {
  body.style.backgroundColor = newVal
})
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/jdWdaqejBLb1hjXF680f?p=preview**

You can replace `<body>` with any querySelectable' element.

Comment: nice! That works! Created an `var divs = queryselectorAll('[id^='color']')` and a loop `[].forEach.call(divs, function(div){ })` through the found divs to change the color with `div.style['background-color'] = $scope.rgbPicker.color`